# Постановка запятой после оборота с «вот»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

> Вот она(,) в коляске.

Почему?

Answer (score 3):

От контекста зависит функция обстоятельства места "в коляске": если это *уточнение* к указанию на "неё" (где именно), то запятая нужна:

> (где же ваша дочка?) Вот она, в коляске.

Если же это описание к фотографии (как "она" изображена), на которую указывают, то запятой не нужно:

> (теперь посмотрите это фото) Вот она в коляске.

Answer (score 1):

В первом ответе сделан **правильный вывод**, но рассуждения выглядят недостаточно ясно, чтобы научиться применять их для решения подобных задач. Это только **частное наблюдение,** которое использовано для конкретного предложения.

С другой стороны,  «чего ж вам больше»? (А.С. Пушкин)  Ну, хотелось бы,чтобы ответ имел общее обоснование, ссвлки на какие-то источники. Я, например, в данном случаае для обоснования грамматики и семантики использую словарь (кроме интонационного анализа).

1. Интонационное решение это задачи очевидно, варианты **легко различаются** по ударной позиции частицы, да и смысл ситуации вполне понятен:

(1) Смотрим на фотографию (указание на  нужное лицо): ***ВОт (здесь) она, в колЯске.***

(2) Смотрим несколько фотографий (указание на всю ситуацию):  ***Вот она в колЯске, а вот уже первые шаги дЕлает.***

Пояснение

**Коммуникативность** – это «модное» направление в современном понимании структуры и грамматики предложения. Другими словами,  мы рассматриваем  определенную **ситуацию общения,** при которой это предложение используется.

Согласно словарю, одним из основных значений частицы ВОТ является указание **на предмет и его расположение** в пространстве. Мы можем обозначить это знаменательными словами, а можем использовать личные и обстоятельственные местоимения. При этом мы  предполагаем, что нашему собеседнику **известно,** о чем идет речь, или считаем, что требуется **дополнительное уточнение.**

В качестве примеров.

– *Что ты ищешь уже полчаса? – Мою книгу по информатике.  – Она на полке.*

– *Где моя книга по информатике* (ты ее вчера брал!)?  –  (1) *Она на пОлке*.  (2) *Вот здЕсь она, на полке*.  (3) *ВОт она, на полке* (только успокойся, пожалуйста).

Можно обратить внимание на то, что в неполном предложении частица ВОТ фактически используется в роли **указательного местоимения** «здесь», то есть происходит **расширение** значения слова.

Из словаря: **ВОТ, частица.** 1. Указывает на кого-, что-л., находящееся или происходящее перед глазами, в непосредственной близости или при рассказывании как бы перед глазами. Вот и наш поезд. Вот вам ключ.  Где ваш дом? - Вот (сопровождается указательным жестом).  Вот парадный подъезд (Некрасов).